# Java Spring/PgSQL operation with timestamp returns interval

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to retrieve data within an interval of timestamp on Java Spring, using a Postgresql database.
One of the queries i'm using, works just fine (It returns data from the last 24 hours):

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT timestamp,lettura,stato FROM dati_impianti 
WHERE sigla_impianto = :impianto and timestamp > now() - interval '24 hours' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC", nativeQuery = true)
  List<ReadingEntity> findLastDay(@Param("impianto") String s);
```

However, when i try to return data with a different timestamp, i get a PSQL exception:

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT timestamp,lettura,stato FROM dati_impianti 
WHERE sigla_impianto = :impianto and timestamp > :timestamp - interval '24 hours' 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC", nativeQuery = true)
  List<ReadingEntity> findDate(@Param("impianto") String s, @Param("timestamp") Timestamp t);
```

And this is the exception i'm getting:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > interval
No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What i cannot understand is that, according to the PostgreSQL documentation, a **timestamp - interval** should return another **timestamp**. However from my query, it seems that i'm comparing a **timestamp** (from the table) with an **interval**, which is wrong. If i try to use directly my timestamp parameter (in the form of **timestamp > :timestamp** without reducing it by an interval), it works but it's not what i was looking for.

I also tried to explicit cast already, by using **:timestamp::timestamp** but this seems to give another kind of error because of Spring and the way it handles the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try explicitly casting your parameter to a `timestamp`:

```
where 
    sigla_impianto = :impianto 
    and timestamp > :timestamp::timestamp - interval '24 hours'
```

Or, possibly:

```
where 
    sigla_impianto = :impianto 
    and timestamp > cast(:timestamp as timestamp) - interval '24 hours'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i said on my question, for some reason this seems not to work, because i get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [timestamp], expecting one of [impianto, timestamp::timestamp]

Comment: @Mastarius: I added another syntax to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this alternative explicit cast method seems to solve the problem